# Separate numbers in paranthesis into different columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, split

Based on the sample data below, how can I seperate the numbers into two different columns i.e., `X` and `Y`?

Sample data

```
Coordinates = c("[-1.74589,6.74885]", NA, NA, NA, NA, "[-1.582775,6.100376]", "[-1.68144,6.63265]", NA, NA, NA, "[-1.98006,6.33484]", "[-0.94156,6.63623]")
df <- data.frame(Coordinates)
```

Desired Output:

```
Coordinates          X         Y
[-1.74589,6.74885]   -1.74589  6.74885 
NA                   NA        NA
NA                   NA        NA
NA                   NA        NA
NA                   NA        NA
[-1.582775,6.100376] -1.582775 6.100376
[-1.68144,6.63265]   -1.68144  6.63265
NA                   NA        NA
NA                   NA        NA
NA                   NA        NA
[-1.98006,6.33484]   -1.98006  6.33484
[-0.94156,6.63623]   -0.94156  6.6362
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::extract`:

```r
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  extract(Coordinates, into = c('X', 'Y'), regex = "\\[(.+),(.+)\\]", convert = TRUE)

           X        Y
1  -1.745890 6.748850
2         NA       NA
3         NA       NA
4         NA       NA
5         NA       NA
6  -1.582775 6.100376
7  -1.681440 6.632650
8         NA       NA
9         NA       NA
10        NA       NA
11 -1.980060 6.334840
12 -0.941560 6.636230
```

Answer (score 2):

One potential option is to use `separate()` from the [tidyr package](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html):

```r
library(tidyverse)

Coordinates = c("[-1.74589,6.74885]",NA, NA, NA, NA, "[-1.582775,6.100376]", "[-1.68144,6.63265]", NA, NA, NA, "[-1.98006,6.33484]", "[-0.94156,6.63623]")
df = data.frame(Coordinates)

df %>%
  separate(Coordinates, into = c("X", "Y"), sep = ",", remove = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(across(X:Y, ~gsub("\\[|\\]", "", .x)))
#>             Coordinates         X        Y
#> 1    [-1.74589,6.74885]  -1.74589  6.74885
#> 2                  <NA>      <NA>     <NA>
#> 3                  <NA>      <NA>     <NA>
#> 4                  <NA>      <NA>     <NA>
#> 5                  <NA>      <NA>     <NA>
#> 6  [-1.582775,6.100376] -1.582775 6.100376
#> 7    [-1.68144,6.63265]  -1.68144  6.63265
#> 8                  <NA>      <NA>     <NA>
#> 9                  <NA>      <NA>     <NA>
#> 10                 <NA>      <NA>     <NA>
#> 11   [-1.98006,6.33484]  -1.98006  6.33484
#> 12   [-0.94156,6.63623]  -0.94156  6.63623
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

NB. unlike @Darren Tsai's `extract()` approach, this does not change the type of "X" and "Y" to numeric

```r
df %>%
  separate(Coordinates, into = c("X", "Y"), sep = ",", remove = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(across(X:Y, ~gsub("\\[|\\]", "", .x))) %>%
  str()
#> 'data.frame':    12 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ Coordinates: chr  "[-1.74589,6.74885]" NA NA NA ...
#>  $ X          : chr  "-1.74589" NA NA NA ...
#>  $ Y          : chr  "6.74885" NA NA NA ...
```

Although you can change "X" and "Y" to numeric if required:

```r
df %>%
  separate(Coordinates, into = c("X", "Y"), sep = ",", remove = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(across(X:Y, ~as.numeric(gsub("\\[|\\]", "", .x)))) %>%
  str()
#> 'data.frame':    12 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ Coordinates: chr  "[-1.74589,6.74885]" NA NA NA ...
#>  $ X          : num  -1.75 NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ Y          : num  6.75 NA NA NA NA ...
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

In the newer version of `tidyr`, we could also use `separate_wider_regex`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   separate_wider_regex(Coordinates, 
   c("\\[", X = "-?[0-9.]+", ",", Y = "-?[0-9.]+", "\\]"), 
         cols_remove = FALSE) %>% 
   relocate(Coordinates, .before = 1)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 × 3
   Coordinates          X         Y       
   <chr>                <chr>     <chr>   
 1 [-1.74589,6.74885]   -1.74589  6.74885 
 2 <NA>                 <NA>      <NA>    
 3 <NA>                 <NA>      <NA>    
 4 <NA>                 <NA>      <NA>    
 5 <NA>                 <NA>      <NA>    
 6 [-1.582775,6.100376] -1.582775 6.100376
 7 [-1.68144,6.63265]   -1.68144  6.63265 
 8 <NA>                 <NA>      <NA>    
 9 <NA>                 <NA>      <NA>    
10 <NA>                 <NA>      <NA>    
11 [-1.98006,6.33484]   -1.98006  6.33484 
12 [-0.94156,6.63623]   -0.94156  6.63623
```

If the type needs to be converted, add `%>% type.convert(as.is = TRUE)` at the end